# AWS ECS CI/CD Downtime

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, gitlab, amazon-ecs

I'm trying to understand from Tutorials and AWS Documentation how the ECS Rolling update works. I'm really confused because I can't solve a small problem.
I am using Gitlab CI/CD and deploying in ECS. I do not use Load Balancer yet, but I think I have to because I'm having a downtime problem. I am using only 1 task for our application, I've set the min and max healthy percent to `0/200` (I think it's false) and when I deploy using:

`- aws ecs update-service --region "${REGION}" --cluster "${CLUSTER_NAME}" --service "${SERVICE_NAME}"  --task-definition "$TASK_DEFINTION_NAME":${REV} --force-new-deployment`

It firsts stops the running task and then starts a new task. Until the service reaches a steady state I can't access my website! Its like 30-40 sec Downtime.
How can I solve this? Should I use Blue/Green Deployment or I am doing something wrong?

Comment: min healthy percent should be 100. Have you tried with that? And how do you ensure same IP for new tasks without load balancer?

Comment: I will try it again now but i think  did it and i had downtime also. I have an elastic ip on my ec2 instance and that's all. Like i said , newbie :D